# Time complexity where inner loop increases according to outer loop

Tags: time-complexity

I have to find the time complexity of the below code. But got confused as the j is increasing acccording to the value of i.

Else I thought it would be $O(n^2)$.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
      for(int j=0;j<n;j+=i) 
      { 
        //Some O(1) Code 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a trick question to me, since if `n` is anything above 0, you would have a non-terminating program.

Comment: @costaparas `n` is just a variable which a user can give any value

Comment: For `n>0` the execution time will be infinite, as in the very first iteration of the outer loop `i=0`, so the increment of the inner loop will be `j=j+0`, causing `j` ro remain 0 forever.

Comment: For `n <0`, instead, the outer loop condition will be false since the very first iteration, so `//Some O(1) Code` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, assuming $n > 0$ then on the first iteration of the outer loop the inner loop will have increment 0 and never terminate.

If instead you meant for the inner loop to increment by i+1, then the total number of iterations is given as:

[Link to latex: I don't have enough reputation to embed images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIJu7.gif)

Where H_n is the n-th harmonic number.

So complexity is O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is not defined for this function since it doesn't terminate on all inputs. In fact, it only terminates for n <= 0.